# How to git add all files in current project, commit, and do a push?

Tags: git, bash

For smaller personal projects, sometimes I just want to make an instant snapshot of the project, so that I don't lost any files or won't messed up the file contents and can't get it back.

So I hope to have a command that will add all files in the current project (no matter which directory I am in within the project directories), commit them, and push it to a remote server, be it github or gitlab.

Is the following a good way to do it; is there a better way?

```
alias gitokpush='git add --all :/ && git com -am "ok" && git push'
```

For the record, `:/` means for the whole working directory (the very top), because `git add .` only adds all files in the current directory and underneath, not necessarily everything from the very top.

Comment: By the way, just for fun, let me introduce you to [`git-fire`](https://github.com/qw3rtman/git-fire).

Comment: @4ae1e1 step 4 is: regret that you have not `git add` yet.  so git-fire will push all the stashes too... that's interesting

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a git alias:

```
 git config --global alias.okpush '!'git add --all :/ && git com -am \"ok\" && git push'
```

Then a `git okpush` would be enough.

Even shorter (and allowing a custom message)

```
git config --global alias.cam '!git commit -a -m '
```

Then: `git cam "ok"`